# asynchronous DNS resolver using asyncore

Tags: python, dns, asyncore

Is there any way to make DNS resolving using Python with asyncore?

I can not install adns and I do not like to use gevent library.

(for URL downloading gevent give me slow performance than syncore.loop)

Answer (score 0):

I asked google your question, and it told me about http://subvert-rpki.hactrn.net/trunk/rpkid/rpki/adns.py which seems to be a DNS client implementation based on asyncore.  So, there you have it, there is a way.

Comment: I am unsure how to install this one. Anyway, I decided not to use async DNS for my project.